# How to transfer all the data from one site to another in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have to transfer all the lists, libraries, and workflows from one site to another. Can someone please explain how we can copy and move each one of these? Another problem that I have is that most of my workflows are List workflows so I cannot really use the export to visio workaround.

I am currently using SPD 2013.

For the list workflow I tried to proceed like this:
http://www.sharepointbasic.com/2012/04/how-to-copy-sharepoint-list-workflow.html?m=1

but all files option did not appear for me. I am one of the site owners. Is there any way I can make it appear?

Comment: see this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/moving-the-contents-of-one-site-to-another-site-in/0ae003a6-192b-4ddc-97ee-8d313169389e?auth=1

Comment: @Farhan Thankyou ! In the end I ended up requesting my IT guys to transfer it for me

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use tools like [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/) if you have lot of site, subsites, list, libraries, workflows, permissions etc.

Comment: Thankyou for answering ! I think I will not be handling a lot of sites,but if you know any quick workarounds it would be super helpful

Comment: May be you can try to save list as a template, include its contents and migrate. A template saves fields, formulas,formatting, and optionally, data as well.

Answer (score 0):

For List,library- you can do quick stp download and stp upload in your new site.
For you code files- keep it in a folder, and from designer  copy it and paste it in new site (designer).
For workflows- if it is 2010 , copy paste will work from one site (Designer) to another Siter(Designer)  but 2013 WF you have to create your WF (best error-free soln).